# check if mongoid habtm relationship was changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

i need send an email if an object was added in relationship

`Account.rb` model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :accounts
```

`User.rb` model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts, inverse_of: :managers
```

In console:

```
[15] pry(main)> a.reload
=> #<Account _id: 5ae71215a8abbc6378b4bee8, code: "ACC5", name: "Account5", manager_ids: []>
[16] pry(main)> u.reload
=> #<User _id: 5ae59b5da8abbc6f3d880a10, name: "Manager 1", account_ids: []>
[17] pry(main)> a.managers << u
=> [#<User _id: 5ae59b5da8abbc6f3d880a10, name: "Manager 1", account_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('5ae71215a8abbc6378b4bee8')]>]
[18] pry(main)> a.reload
=> #<Account _id: 5ae71215a8abbc6378b4bee8, code: "ACC5", name: "Account5", manager_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('5ae59b5da8abbc6f3d880a10')]>
[19] pry(main)> a.managers.select { |e| e.new_record? }.any?
=> false
[20] pry(main)> a.managers.any? {|a| a.changed?}
=> false
```

i've tried with `a.managers.select { |e| e.new_record? }.any?` and `a.managers.any? {|a| a.changed?}` but i'm always getting **false**

Thank you!

Comment: Try this gem `mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking` https://github.com/Polarion/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with changeable mongoid module `Module: Mongoid::Changeable`

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Changeable

But, you should not create the relationship of this way:

```
a.managers << u
```

To check methods like `a.manager_ids_changed?` or `a.manager_ids_was`, you need to create the relationship of this way:

```
a.manager_ids << u.id
```

Thank you!